# JQuery Mobile Tab Bar Causing Rendering Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile Tab Bar that is not behaving as expected:

```
<footer data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <nav data-role="navbar">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#landmarks" id="LandmarksTab" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active">Landmarks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#map" id="MapTab" data-icon="custom">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#more" id="MoreTab" data-icon="custom">More</a></li>
           </ul>
      </nav>
</footer>
```

When the tab bar initially loads, it looks normal, however, when navigating to "more" or "map", then the buttons no longer show an `active` state. Also, after navigating through pages, sometimes, the first "landmarks" page appears below the active page, if the user scrolls down.

Here is a link to the complete project: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B10/index.html

Is there something wrong with my tab bar?

Thanks.