# Can't Modify innerHTML from pageshow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am making a JQuery Mobile web app, and am running into an interesting problem. I am trying to dynamically inject the contents of a page from within the `pageshow` function. I know the `pageshow` function is being called, because the `console.log` prints correctly, however, the test HTML does not appear in the page.

Code for `pageShow` function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < landmarkList.length; i++)
{
    var pageId = landmarkList[i].landmarkLink.substring(1, landmarkList[i].landmarkLink.length);
    $(document).on('pageshow','#' + pageId,function(){
        console.log("Init Map for page: " + pageId);
        document.getElementById("map_" + pageId).innerHTML = 'TEST';
    });
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B9/index.html. When a row is clicked on, the `pageShow` function loads, but the innerHTML does not add to the `div` and also does not produce an error.

Any ideas why this is not occurring?

Thanks.

Comment: It does say TEXT in the DIV below the big image. What browser are you using? Verify it works in other browsers or not.

Comment: Hmmm. I am using Safari, Firefox and Chrome on OS X 10.9. What configuration are you using that you see it?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your HTML so I can make the example below accurate :)

Comment: Here is the HTML for the page: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B9/index.html here is the JS that runs the page: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B9/js/landmarks.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the *delegated event handler* (it is not designed for one per element). You do not need the loop at all if you can extract the page id from the page.

basically the `pageId` value in your loop is no longer valid when it hits this line (as it is being called back later, long after the value has been modified by the loop):

```
document.getElementById("map_" + pageId).innerHTML = 'TEST';
```

**If you can provide an example of your HTML I will make this accurate**, but something like:

```
// e.g. Match pageShow events from any pages with data-role=
$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
    var $page = $(this);
    // Extract the page id from the page element (pageId is locally scoped to this callback)
    var pageId = $page.attr('id');
    console.log("Init Map for page: " + pageId);
    $("#map_" + pageId).html('TEST');
 });
```

*More than likely there is a relationship between your map and pages, but without the HTML is is difficult to provide better selectors.*

### Update:

Looking at the actual page HTML, each "page" has a `data-role="page"` attribute. That should be the target of the delegated event selector. You can then take the id from that page, prefix it with `map_' and find the matching map directly.

It can be shortened to:

```
// e.g. Match pageShow events from any pages with data-role=
$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
    console.log("Init Map for page: " + this.id);
    $("#map_" + this.id).html('TEST');
});
```

### Delegated event handlers:

Delegate event handlers work by listening at an *ancestor* of the desired elements, *then* when the chosen event bubbles up to that element, *then* it applies the jQuery selector to find desired elements, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*.

If you do not have a convenient, non-changing ancestor, use `$(document).on`, but never `$('body').on` as `body` has some weird side-effects with delegated events.

Delegated events have several benefits:

- Simplifies and separates the event code.
- You do not have the overhead of adding individual handlers to items.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Did I provide enough Sample HTML to make the example accurate?

Comment: Page ID is created from a substring of the name (but I can put "page-" in front of it). The maps are created by putting "map_" + pageId.

Comment: Done... Try it in your code. Get rid of your `for` loop (not needed).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. How come the loop is not necessary and it only shows for the detail pages? (I am fascinated because it only shows in the right places, but I don't see how it knows what pages to show on) Is this because it searches for the "map_" id?

Comment: Thank you. So after this function is called, does this method run for every page, but it does not make the substitution, because the other pages don't have the map id?

Comment: It will run for any `data-role="page"` element, present or future, on the page, but if there is no matching `map_` id then `$("#map_" + this.id)` returns an empty jQuery collection/object and `html()` will do nothing.

Comment: Ok, got it. If you have time, would you mind helping me with this question (it is based on the same example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247817/jquery-mobile-tab-bar-causing-rendering-problems